# Execute and Wait for Rest Webservice

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, web-services, rest

I need to implement an application that allow users to upload file. The application will then process the file and then return result.

My current application is using:

- Spring
- Hibernate
- Rest web service

Now here is the problem.
What I want is to when the users upload a file, the web service should execute and wait for a response until the server return a result. On my client I should be able to get the current status of the file upload processing. If is still in processing, it should be return some value to denote processing. Timeout should not occur as well while waiting.

How do I go about doing it? Any advice?

Comment: http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-multi-file-upload-with-progress-bar/

Comment: Post to a URL, return a status code of `ACCEPTED` (i.e. 202) and with a `Location` where to get the status of the upload. You can then poll this URL until you receive a 201 (`CREATED` with a new location header where to get the end result). Something similar is used in the Spring Restbucks sample.

Comment: @M.Deinum then in this case should the task (in this case the upload method) inside the web service be a async task?